# What is the rationale for requiring data URIs to be Base64 encoded?

Tags: base64, data-uri

A [Data URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) allows an external resource like an image to be inlined directly inside of web page.  What is the design justification, either historical or current, for requiring that data URIs be Base64 encoded, given that they could be more efficiently encoded in other simple formats e.g. 8-bit ASCII?

Comment: So you want to mix raw binary data into a text format that supports various encodings? And you're expecting this to work reliably?

Comment: @muistooshort can you elaborate on any examples specific to data URIs where this might cause things to go wrong?

Comment: What do you plan to do about bytes that just happen to be double quotes? Ampersands? `>` or `<`? Base64 is text safe, encoding safe, and every browser will already understand it. Grab a random binary file and find all the zero bytes, now see how well a text tool deals with that.

Answer (score 0):

Data uris don't have to be Base64 encoded; try going to this url:

```
data:text/plain;
```

Data uris still work without Base64 encoding.